# how to replace %s with one variable in python

Tags: python

I have a string like

```
strTemp='i don\'t want %s repeat the %s variable again %s and again %s'%('aa','aa','aa','aa')
```

I want to replace all the %s with 'aa', so I have to repeat the 'aa' for many times, how can I tell the program that I want to replace all the %s just with the same variable, so I needn't type the variable for times

Answer (score 7):

The % operator is discouraged. Use `str.format` instead.

```
strTemp='i don\'t want {0} repeat the {0} variable again {0} and again {0}'.format('aa')
```

Comment: The `{}` syntax is newer and spiffier.  You can do a bunch of things with it that you can't with the `%` syntax.  And I am under the impression the `%` syntax was removed from Python 3 but that may be wrong.

Comment: `{}` is definitely more powerful, but I don't see how that results in `%` being discouraged.

Comment: @Tim http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format says "[`.format()`] is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code."

Comment: Faster than I expected, both the two methods are feasible, and I want to try {} syntax

Comment: @Tim, however, I was mistaken, `%`-style formatting does still exist in Python 3: http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: Ahem, % is faster. Some, perhaps, prefer str.format(), saying that "The formatting operations described here are obsolete and may go away in future versions of Python" about %, but the same was said about the cnf={} keyword argument to Tkinter widgets.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the named formatting argument syntax:

```
strTemp='i don\'t want %(key)s repeat the %(key)s variable again %(key)s and again %(key)s' % {
    'key': 'replacement value',
}
```

Not a lot better necessarily since you have to repeat a key four times, but if your replacement value is long, or is a calculation with side effects that you *really* don't want to do more than once, this is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

if you have really many repetitions and don't want to type `{0}` or `%(var)s` you may consider a seldom used (placeholder-)char, which gets replaced, e.g.:

```
p='µ µµ µµµ µµµµ µµµµµ {1}'.replace('µ','{0}').format(' muahaha ', 'duh')
```

or for a single substition variable:

```
strTemp='i don\'t want µ repeat the µ variable again µ and again µ'.replace('µ','aa')
```

Comment: For maximum compression and complete unreadability, you can use `reduce` to chain together lots of replacements with minimal size overhead (only need to specify the function and a list of arguments). I actually wrote a script to compress string literals this way once (it also uses other tricks to reduce size).

Comment: funny idea! ;-) but i already overstreched the OPs original intention,  on the other hand it's never wrong to be reminded of such nice included batteries ;-)

Comment: @Antimony: btw i use the abilities of my editor (vim) for these superfluous typings: inoremap ¹ {0} inoremap ² {1} .... ;-)